# Create a bidding history component

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.player-nickname {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.bid-text {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bidding Game</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="grid-container" id="gridContainer"></div>
<button onclick="addBid()">Add</button>

<script>
  const players = [
    { nickname: 'one', inactive: false },
    { nickname: 'two', inactive: false },
  ];

  const bidsArray = [
    { player: 0, bidType: 'level', level: '2', suit: 'NT' },
    { player: 1, bidType: 'level', level: '3', suit: 'S' },
    { player: 0, bidType: 'double' },
    { player: 1, bidType: 'pass' },
    { player: 0, bidType: 'pass' },
    { player: 1, bidType: 'double' },
    { player: 0, bidType: 'pass' },
    { player: 1, bidType: 'double' },
  ];

  let bids = [];
  const dealer = 0;
  let bidMap = new Map();

  for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    const playerIndex = i;
    bidMap.set(playerIndex, []);
  }

  function updateBidMap() {
    bids.forEach((bid) => {
      const { player } = bid;

      if (!bidMap.has(player)) bidMap.set(player, []);

      if (player !== dealer && bidMap.get(player).length === 0) bidMap.get(player).push({});

      const playerBids = bidMap.get(player);
      const existingBidIndex = playerBids.findIndex(existingBid => existingBid.bidType === bid.bidType && existingBid.level === bid.level && existingBid.suit === bid.suit);

      if (existingBidIndex !== -1) {
        playerBids[existingBidIndex] = bid;
      } else {
        playerBids.push(bid);
      }
    });
  }

  function getBidText(bid) {
    if (bid.bidType === 'pass') {
      return 'Pass';
    } else if (bid.bidType === 'double') {
      return 'Double';
    } else if (bid.bidType === 'level') {
      return `${bid.level}${bid.suit}`;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  function addBid() {
    if (bidsArray.length > 0) {
      const newBid = bidsArray.shift();
      bids.push(newBid);
      updateBidMap();
      updateUI();
    } else {
      console.log("No more bids in bidsArray");
    }
  }

  function updateUI() {
    const gridContainer = document.getElementById('gridContainer');
    gridContainer.innerHTML = '';

    players.forEach((player, playerIndex) => {
      if (bidMap.has(playerIndex)) {
        const bidContainer = document.createElement('div');
        bidContainer.classList.add('bid-container');

        const playerNickname = document.createElement('div');
        playerNickname.classList.add('player-nickname');
        playerNickname.textContent = player.nickname;

        bidContainer.appendChild(playerNickname);

        bidMap.get(playerIndex).forEach(bid => {
          const bidText = document.createElement('div');
          bidText.classList.add('bid-text');
          bidText.style.visibility = getBidText(bid) == null ? 'hidden' : 'auto';
          bidText.textContent = getBidText(bid);
          bidContainer.appendChild(bidText);
        });

        gridContainer.appendChild(bidContainer);
      }
    });
  }

  // Initial UI update
  updateUI();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to create a history component, which will be like this

There are two players in the game. If the player makes a bid, it will be added to the bids array.

```
  const bids = [
    { player: 1, bidType: 'level', level: '1', suit: 'NT' },
    { player: 0, bidType: 'level', level: '2', suit: 'NT' },
    { player: 1, bidType: 'level', level: '3', suit: 'S' },
    { player: 0, bidType: 'double' },
    { player: 1, bidType: 'pass' },
    { player: 0, bidType: 'pass' },
    { player: 1, bidType: 'double' },
    { player: 0, bidType: 'pass' },
    { player: 1, bidType: 'double' },
  ];
```

`In this, if I change the dealer value to 1, it should add the empty value in the player 0's Map, if not don't do anything`

Based on this bids array I want to create a history component. The game can be played on browser -

The dealer is 0, so in Player 0's screen - the bid History should be like this,

[player0' screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb0yn.png)

in player1's screen, the bid history should be like this,

[Player1's screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8LrW.png)

How to implement this logic in svelte. I already made a component,
this is the link for that - you can run it and see the output.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/falling-glitter-t3yyy9?file=%2FButton.svelte%3A21%2C19

Comment: @JaromandaX it is not working as expected, my logic needs to modified

Comment: In this code, if the dealer is 0 and it is in the player 1's screen, the empty key should not be added to the other player but it is adding